# Changing reference data and maintaining "history"

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design

I have been working on a project, when I hit a design dilema for what I believe is quite common situation. Please let me know how do you handle it. 
Let's assume that we are building a webapplication for a shop. There is a catalogs table, with a number of rows, e.g.

ID | name | price

1. | Toy car | 10$
2. | Teddy Bear | 2$

And orders table with payment means. 
How should I store data about order details, meaning product bought? The main concern is how to handle changes in catalogs table like price modification.

Solutions I came up with are:

1. Have a table order_details with structure similar to catalog and many-to-one relation with orders table. When a user buys sth, necessary data is copied to order_details table from catalogs table. This requires big storage as we copy all(or at least some) of the columns, and in case of column modification in catalogs table, there is a need to propagate the changes to order_detals.
2. Another idea is to utilize mechanism of slowly changing dimensions (from data warehousing). Catalogs table requires additional columns like:

ID | name | price | version

1. | Toy car | 10$ | 1
2. | Teddy Bear | 2$ | 1
3. | Teddy Bear | 4$ | 2

And order_details table with many-to-one relation to orders table and many-to-one relation with catalogs table. In this case there is the same number of rows in order_details table, but there is smaller number of columns. The con of this approach is a need to manage the versions of products.

Comment: duplicates: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/258234/best-approach-for-an-online-store-which-changes-its-product-s-price-over-time; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469803/how-to-handle-price-fluctuations-in-an-invoice-application; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818965/how-to-properly-relate-items-to-pricing-data-taking-price-change-history-into-a

Comment: you are right. I was looking for sth like it, just when it comes to design questions sometimes it is hard ask the "right question"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer to a similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38707496/database-versioning-without-history-tables/38735711#38735711) which discusses Version Normal Form.

You need to normalize the price (and any other data you want to track) to a separate table. Your FKs will continue to work normally. All you have to do is get the price that was in effect when the order was made. This is a bit tricky but not difficult.

Comment: This is similar to Jaco0646 answer and I find it appealing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general your db design depends on your shop application logic. But I can guess that this approach will help you:

Create a table `catalog_prices (priceId, productId, price, date)` and in
catalogs table change `price` column to `priceId`. So,
every product will have one current price and table catalog_prices will have product price history. So, query

```sql
SELECT c.ID, c.name, p.price FROM catalogs AS c 
INNER JOIN catalog_prices AS p ON c.priceId = p.priceId
```

will return all products with prices and query

```sql
SELECT c.ID, c.name, p.price, p.date FROM catalogs AS c 
INNER JOIN catalog_prices AS p ON c.ID = p.productId
```

will return all price history.

Next in `order_details` table add `productPriceId` column. So query

```sql
SELECT d.ID, d.orderId, c.name, p.price FROM order_details AS d 
INNER JOIN catalog_prices AS p ON p.priceId = d.productPriceId
INNER JOIN catalogs AS c ON p.productId = c.ID
```

will return order details with prices.

This solution will add additional join for showing catalog products and ordered products but allows reduce data duplication – prices will be stored in one place. And you will be able to see product price history.